# Retrieve dynamically created entity during runtime using Objectify

Tags: java, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have a web application where the entities are created at runtime. e.g. for each `company` registered in the application, I am creating an entity in Google datastore. The entity names look like `ABC_PVT_LTD`, `XYZ_PVT_LTD`. This means we don't have a corresponding Java class with `@Entity` annotation. I only know the name of the entity.

How do I retrieve records from these entities using Objectify by just knowing the name of the entity?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Objectify? Objectify is a tool for mapping between the datastore and Java objects. If you just want to store arbitrary entities in the datastore, use the Java low-level API.

Comment: Yes, currently I have used the low-level API. But, wanted to know if Objectify has this capability.

Comment: You can save() and load() low-level Entity objects, which sounds like what you want. It's not much more sophisticated than just passing those objects off to the low-level api.